# Can't change any properties for an existing AWS::AutoScaling::Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm a little baffled; I don't seem to be able to change any of the properties associated with an existing AWS::AutoScaling::Trigger.

This seems like an awfully basic thing you would want to do once you've got things set up; perhaps adjusting the period, breachduration, increments, upper+lower threshold.

If I take my template, just change the "UpperThreshold" property, and try to update my existing stack with it, I get this error and the update fails:

```
The following resource(s) failed to update: [AutoscalingTrigger].
Updating the properties of AWS::AutoScaling::Trigger resources is not supported.
```

Suggestions?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or not, but I came across this note on the [UpdateAutoScalingGroup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateAutoScalingGroup.html) page:

> "To update an Auto Scaling group with a launch configuration that has the InstanceMonitoring flag set to False, you must first ensure that collection of group metrics is disabled. Otherwise, calls to UpdateAutoScalingGroup will fail. If you have previously enabled group metrics collection, you can disable collection of all group metrics by calling DisableMetricsCollection."